# Storing classes in a boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, json, boost

I'm working on a program to record information about the variables within a program. I'd like to group this information by file -> function -> variable.

The boost::property_tree seemed like a good fit for this as I could store an Access object at a path in the tree (`file.function.variable`) and then easily convert the tree to XML, JSON, etc.

Say I'm recording the number of uses of a variable. I can have a class Access that keeps track of the number of writes and reads to a variable. I can then store this object at file.function.variable in the tree. Each time the variable is accessed I can find the variable in the tree and update information about it.

However, I cannot figure out how to store a class in the tree. I assume there is something I need to implement or subclass, but the documentation doesn't address what I'm trying to do.

Is there a solution to my problem? Is there a better alternative to boost::property_tree?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::property_tree` is designed to hold *text data*.  That's what makes it suitable for exporting to XML, JSON, etc.

Modify your class `Access` so it  includes methods for converting to/from text and store that text in the tree.

Comment: I don't really want to have a giant nested structure like that as it will grow larger as nesting becomes deeper. For example, I may like to store stuff by folder->file->function->variable in the future. Ideally I'd like to add a method to my class that allows it to convert itself to XML/JSON when write_json(tree) is called on a tree containing it.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to store a class as a node and have a method that converts it to the appropriate text format when the conversion starts? I'd like to store the Access objects in the tree as they will be updated as my program runs, I can't just convert them and store the text as I need a way to access and update them later.

Comment: @tgt Absolutely it can be done, but based on your unique list of requirements, there may not be a pre-written solution available to you.

Comment: What's unique about my set of requirements? I just want to store a class in a tree and have a method or two to convert it to an appropriate format. One solution could be: if each node in the ptree is ptree I could make my class a subclass of ptree and update this tree when the properties of the class are changed. This, however, doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Thanks. I must be doing something else incorrectly then. I shall investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the idea of the tree and just stick with a flat map of key value pairs.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, Access> accesses;
// add one access
accesses["file.function.variable"] += 1;
```

You just need to write a routine that produces the JSON from its content, which should be straightforward. (Assuming the first part of the key is always the file, the second is always the function, the third is always the variable.)